# Dynamic Proxy with OpenSSH and windows

Tags: proxy, putty, openssh, squid

Ok, so the goal is to be able to utilize the dynamic proxy method that OpenSSH provides with the -D option on the Linux client, such that any connection requests made against a local port are forwarded and proxied by the remote ssh server.

Has anyone done this on a windows ssh client? Have information, the point is to only require a remote host to run simply OpenSSH, not an OpenSSH and squid combo.

To reiterate, I am looking for a client on windows that mimics the Linux client's -D option.

Answer (score 1):

[PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) is a commonly used ssh client for windows, its also a standalone executable so you can put it on a usb drive and use it anywhere. It has dynamic forwarding with the -D option as well.

Comment: I am using the dynamic option in putty, with an open-ssh server on the other end. I am getting connection resets instantly whenever I try to use the localport as a proxy.

Comment: @petekalo: Ctrl+rightclick on PuTTY's window and open the event log. It should tell you why connections are being refused.

Comment: Also, PuTTY comes with a `plink` tool which can be used from command-line: `plink -v -N -D 1234 user@host`

Comment: @grawity Thanks for the logging tip!

I am getting "Forwarded connection refused by server" in the putty logs

AllowTcpForwarding yes is set in sshd_config 

dont know is going on.

Comment: @petekalo: The message means that connections are refused by the final host, not by the SSH server. Open an interactive SSH session and try opening a TCP connection yourself. For example, `socat tcp:<host>:<port> stdio` or `nmap -sT -p <port> <host>` or `telnet <host> <port>`...